# Stm32 CubeIDE debbuging not working. Tracing Not supported

Tags: debugging, stm32, stm32cubeide

I am using cubeIDE version 1.8.0 and NucleoF746ZG microcontroller for my project. I have made the codes and when I compile and run they work properly without errors and warnings. But the problem is that when I try to debug, It doesn't work. I mean the debug code uploads to the board but no cursor shows up at the breakpoints. I have tried to make some breakpoints and hault the program at them but no cursor comes to them.

I have opened a trace control tab and it says "Tracing is not supported". I don't know why that happens. The only thing that I know is that after installing the software, It didn't recognized my st-link. It was fixed after replacing the libusb-1.0.dll to a newer version of it. That was the thing that I have changed. But I don't think that it will affect since compiling and running works properly.

If anyone has encountered this issue or if you have any clues about a cause for this matter, please let me know. And request me if you need any more details from my side. I have attached two screenshots for reference.

Thanks and Kind Regards...

[image]
[image]

Comment: In my case, it was not the same. st-link was connected, but only debugging was not possible. The problem occurred when importing a project created in another version of CUBEIDE. After clean the project, modifying the .ioc file and completely regenerating the code solved the problem.

Comment: The trace functionality is different than the basic debugging. usually it is a functionality of the chip (on STM32 it is called ETM or ITM) that is exploited by the tool. Unless STM32CubeIDE gives to "tracing" a different meaning

Comment: Same issue, cleaning doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

If your breakpoints have a cross through them, it might be because you pressed `Ctrl+Alt+B` at some point. This happened to me when I was trying to remember the build shortcut after using VS Code and switching back to STM32CubeIDE.

[image: Skipped breakpoint]

Check to see if 'Skip all breakpoints' is enabled, and ensure it's disabled.

[image: Skip all breakpoints]